# Composer installing packages for newer version

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, composer-php, php-8

I run app in docker on my computer and I have a problem with updating php in composer. When I change php version in `require` composer updates packages to version higher that I specified and get syntax error.

I am updating php from 7.4 to 8.0, the steps i made were:

I change php require to this (i have tried `"^8.0.0"` and `"~8.0.0"` too)

```
"require": {
    "php": "8.0.*",
    ...
```

then I change Dockerfile to pull from newer image `FROM php:8.0-apache` (i have checked php version inside the container and it is `PHP 8.0.27 (cli)`)

next I run `docker-compose exec -T app composer update --prefer-dist --ignore-platform-reqs`

then new lock file is generated and there is for example this which was installed as dependency of another package, i dont have it as my require

```
{
    "name": "monolog/monolog",
    "version": "3.2.0",
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        ...
    },
```

when i check the package which has `monolog` as dependency there is this `"monolog/monolog": "^1.17||^2.0||^3.0",` so older version was available but newer was picked and installed even when it does not meet the requirements.
Can someone help and tell me what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Why do you use `--ignore-platform-reqs`? Also, are you sure this problem is relatd to Docker itself?

Comment: Because when i dont then the php version and other ext libs are checked on my platform/my computer and not in the container where i run the update. I thought that this was the option for this case. And second question, i dont know where the problem is, i cant rule out docker because I run this app in docker

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, `--ignore-platform-reqs`  does exactly what it should do: it ignores the platform requirements. This also ignores that you want to use PHP 8.0 and not any later one

Comment: Sure. Thank you. That is something new.... Then, please, do you know any other way to generate new composer.lock file, if i dont want to install `php`, `mysql`, `ext-json`, `ext-redis`, `ext-gd`, `ext-curl`, `ext-openssl` ... on my computer and want to require specific version?

Comment: okay, i have it, thank you very much,. i used for example `--ignore-platform-req=ext-redis` for missing packages on my computer, maybe you could post your comment as answer so i can mark it?